# WSL over remote powershell has no effect

Tags: powershell, wsl2

I'm connecting to another computer through a remote powershell session, but when I use the `wsl` command nothing happens:

```
PS C:\Users\Ian\Documents> Enter-PSSession -Credential $credential -ComputerName iansdesktop
[iansdesktop]: PS C:\Users\ianne\Documents> wsl
[iansdesktop]: PS C:\Users\ianne\Documents>
```

[image: "1".Dump();]

Is there something I can do to start wsl remotely?

P.S. both machines are running Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation here is that `Enter-PSSession` is an interactive session,
but with no connection to your local session.
This means that you don't see the output of the commands that you enter.

If you wish to start a truly interactive session that returns its output
to your local computer,
you should rather use Remote Desktop Connection or SSH.